# fastest xslt 1.0, and xslt 2.0 processors in terms of performance

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

which xslt processor you would suggest, for xslt 1.0 and xslt 2.0 respectively, in terms of performance? Say one has a huge xml file, and would like to make the conversion time faster. Does the language it is implemented play a very important role?
For instance, i would like to try a go language implementation, if one has to suggest such an implementation, or a c language processor?

To be clear. I have made things in both, xslt 1.0 and xslt 2.0, so i need a way to make the process faster on each specification.

Comment: P:erformance of one processor might be good for one stylesheet and bad for another one or another input/stylesheet combination so you will need to measure. https://www.xml.com/articles/2017/01/26/revving-xslt-10-engines-are-they-all-same/ for instance is a performance comparison of some engines with the aim of comparison XSLT 1.0 performance although it then goes ahead and uses Saxon 9 which is an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor. It also depends certainly of which processor you have access to, not all processors are available on all platforms and for some you need to buy a commercial licese.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation language for the processor isn't a very important factor. Sure, different languages pose different challenges: if you write an XSLT processor in C (or any other language without garbage collection) then you have to put a lot of effort into memory management, but that affects the cost and effort of writing the processor more than the performance it ends up achieving.

Performance isn't one dimensional. Different processors will compare differently depending on the actual stylesheet. In addition, it depends what you measure: processor start-up time, stylesheet compile time, source document parsing/building time, single-threaded performance or multi-threaded performance. There's no substitute for making your own measurements tailored to your particular workload.

If the performance of your workload isn't meeting requirements, then seeing how it fares on a different XSLT processor is one of the actions you can take to try and solve the problem. But there are many other actions you can take as well, and some of them may be less disruptive. Before trying a different XSLT processor, check to make sure that XSLT processing is actually a critical component of your overall system performance: I've seen plenty of cases were I've been called in to look at perceived XSLT performance issues and it turned out on investigation that the issues were nothing to do with XSLT processing. And where it is XSLT processing, sometimes a simple change to your XSLT code, or to the way you run the XSLT processor, will make a vast saving.

Comment: "seeing how it fares on a different XSLT processor is one of the actions you can take to try and solve the problem." What processor should i try, given the fact that this is the only parameter under question?

Comment: We don't know where you're starting from and what platform constraints you have. But of course you should use Saxon ;-)

Comment: i am am on an ubuntu 16.04 machine, now i use SAXON (Saxon-B) the Open Source variant of Saxon for releases up to and including version 9.1

Comment: If you move to the latest release of Saxon-EE 9.8 (or even Saxon-HE 9.8) then it will do some things much faster than Saxon-B 9.1, but many other things will take around the same time. Hence the message that it all depends on your code, you must make your own measurements and find where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Based on your experience, which version  from the following you would suggest? (Java, .NET, and C/C++/PHP), given that i am planning to use HE: Saxon Home Edition (open source) as you suggested version 9.8

Comment: If you're using Saxon then its native platform is Java and that will run faster than the .NET or C versions.